# jquery selector last thumb at the line when align is left (advanced jquery)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

**EDIT: carefully! last BOX at the FIRST line! Width of the CONTAINER can CHANGE at any time. IE. container width 1000px = 10 Boxes per line! Need to select last 10th box at the line. But width of the container can change**
:

[CHECK EXAMLE](http://1lj.net/ex.html)

Do you see boxes? ok. need to select last box at the line (8th box) when page is full screen. When browser windows less that 800px - another box will be at the last line possition (ie 7th, 6th, 5th)

**======================================**

As you see, here is "content div" that contain small boxes. Content div can change own width for user screen resolution at any time.  And each "box" will arranged in lines on the screen, but the last box every time willl be different.

How to get ID of the last box on first or second line at the screen with jquery? 
Is there any universal methods to get ID from the line of boxes even if the size of content div changed?

Example of initial source:

```
<style type="text/css">
.box{float: left;
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
.content {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
</style>

<div class=content>
<div class=box id=xxx1>xxx</div>
<div class=box id=xxx2>xxx</div>
...
<div class=box id=xxx200>xxx</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I add some notes and example of the page. when page is full screen, i need 7th box on it. when you make your browser window less that 800px, the last 7th box will move to the next line. And I need 6th or less box when its going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now i know what you want, so for this you can use following code:

```
var top = $('.box:first').offset().top; 
var firstLine = $('.box').filter(function(){
    return $(this).offset().top == top;
});
// now you can select any of first line element

  firstLine.last(); // Select Last item of first line
  firstLine.eq(3); // box 4
```

in this case i get first  box offset and compare it with other boxes top offset ...

Comment: no. this solution will select last box on the page, i need last box of first line! see example of the page please!

Comment: @abrahab what is first line?? are you want select from box1 to box7?

Comment: @mr-ok , thanks! worked http://1lj.net/ex2.html !! Now, also add to your solution functionality to find last visible row on the screen (also NOT on the page) and select last thumb from this row/line :)))

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = $('.content').width() / 100;
    var id = $('.box').eq(w - 1).attr('id');
})
```

Comment: no. this solution will select last box on the page, i need last box of first line! see example of the page!

Comment: no. :(  new variant var id = $('.box').eq('9').attr('id') will only select last thumb on the first line if div class=content can not change its width, but it can change width at any time when user browser window is less that 800px. if 500px (only 4th thumbs will be per line)

Comment: @abrahab got it, you should first check the width, do you mean this?

Comment: yes, maybe. check actual current width of the content div, than check the width of the box and divide DIV_CONTENT_width / BOX_WIDTH = will get how much BOXes per line. than select last box from line. something line this waybe.

Comment: yes, something like this. will $('.content').width() return ACTUAL CURRENT size on the screen of the DIV=CONTENT or it will return width from css?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".box").last()[0].id; // returns the ID of the last element with class "box" found
```

Comment: This is the `Advanced jQuery` part?

Comment: @GabrielSantos: I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean. Could you elaborate a little? :-)

Comment: Are you sure that this will select last box from FIRST line on any user resolution???

Comment: @abrahab: Not sure what you mean by "first line", but this will select the last box found on any user resolution.

Comment: Are you imagine the output of the source code? for example if the CONTENT DIV will be 1000px (max) it will contain 10 BOXes per line! I need to select 10th BOX on this width, but WIDTH can changed at be 900px = 9 boxes per line. Last list from first line.

Comment: I'm joking about the part that abrahab says "(advanced jquery)" lol

Comment: You does not know the solution. Read the condition carefully and see example.